# 1099B has two transactions, for one stock, listed under long term but dates span under 1 year. How to file?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099

I'm finishing up my taxes and I have a 1099-B where for one of the stocks, two transactions occurred where the purchase and sell date were under a year apart but is listed under long term with box D checked. I've included a screenshot of the transactions below. The ones in question are the first and third. Both were losses and one was a wash sale.

The tax filing site I'm using triggered the error message that these two transactions did not meet the time frame for "long term" which is true. My question is how do I file this properly? I did reach out to the broker and they just said talk to a tax expert. I called a few to just ask this question but everyone I called wouldn't answer without us paying to have them file it.

Logically, it would make sense to just mark these as short term. But is that the correct thing to do?

[image: Snapshot of actual transactions in question]

Comment: It looks like wash sales? You get the original wash sold purchase date for the holding period.

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/132863/64920).